# Different CREATE_TIME for tables in Master and Slave

Tags: mysql, replication

We have found that the value of **CREATE_TIME** column in **information_schema.tables** for many tables was different in **MASTER** and **SLAVE**. Upon going through the logs, it was found that the **CREATE_TIME** value in the **SLAVE** was that of the *scheduled weekly OPTIMIZE routine*. Hence it can be inferred that the **OPTIMIZE TABLE** statements are causing the TABLES to be *recreated in SLAVE*. However, the scheduled job runs on **MASTER only**. But the **CREATE_TIME** in **MASTER** is not getting affected.

Why is the **OPTIMIZE TABLE** command behaving differently on **MASTER and SLAVE**? And if the table is being reconstructed at **SLAVE**, is the table becoming temporarily *unavailable* during that period?

Comment: Show us the script that runs on the "master only".  In general, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is a waste of time for InnoDB tables.

Comment: @RickJames Seems like It was due to differing values of `innodb_optimize_fulltext_only` on MASTER and SLAVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `innodb_optimize_fulltext_only` was ON in master but OFF in slave. As a result, the **OPTIMIZE TABLE** commands were being *skipped* in Master server.

Comment: And you might want that if you read only on the Slave(s).